# Lending someone 500 dollars

Tags: usd-us-dollar, lending

Consider a hypothetical situation. Person A lends person B 500 American dollars on 0% interest. Now American government prints more money such that the old 1 dollar is now equivalent 10 new dollars. 
According to law how much should person B return to person A 500 or 5000 dollar?

Comment: Do you mean that the American government actually swaps everyone’s currency and savings, giving them ten new dollars for every old dollar, or do you mean that inflation devalues the dollar so that it takes ten dollars to buy what one dollar used to?

Comment: I meant inflation

Comment: In that case the accepted answer is correct. If you want to protect yourself against inflation, you charge an appropriate rate of interest on the loan — that’s one of the main things that interest is for.

Comment: Maybe make that clear in the question, because the question is completely different from "inflation". The question implies that the government created a new currency to replace the old dollar. Printing money is generally not the problem leading to inflation in the US (it most definitely is elsewhere). If you loan money at 0% interest you have already conceded that you will lose money to inflation (as RonJohn made clear)

Comment: @Mike Scott: But this isn't a case of inflation, it's a deliberate currency devaluation.  You can charge interest to cover the expected rate of inflation (which is a gradual & continuous process), but you can't do that with a devaluation, which is a singular spike.  (Mathematically, it's the difference between a continuous, differentiable function and a discontinuous one that has no derivative.)

Comment: *I meant inflation* Inflation isn't the result of a one-time decision to suddenly print enough money that it is devalued by a factor of ten. As written, it's hard to determine if you're actually interested in such an unusual, sudden, and severe change in value, or if you're actually interested in how inflation "normally" works in the sense that it's a gradual, continuous, and somewhat predictable change. Can you clarify?

Comment: i do not think the debate going on in the comments matters. Time value of money and the risk of loss of real value are realities in our currency system.  Unless the government makes a new script that replaces the old script, it does not matter. If I have a US dollar bill from 1980 and a US dollar bill from 2019, they are both worth the same. The fact that in 1980, I could get more stuff (in many but not all categories) with it is irrelevant. The fact that two years ago it could be traded for more or fewer euros or Yen or whatever is also irrelevant.

Comment: @xyious why isn't printing money in US a problem

Comment: Because historically other factors were far more important to inflation than the printing of money. Of course you could try to make a case of inflation being calculated incorrectly, but there really isn't a good way. If the oil price rises significantly then inflation will go up because it's a big part of people's lives and a factor in inflation. It has nothing to do with whether or not new money is created. In the long term, obviously, inflation is limited to how much money is actually around.

Comment: @AkashKarnatak there's 10x as much digital US currency as there is paper currency and coins.  Thus, **printing** more will have a minimal impact on inflation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The (written or unwritten, does not make a difference) contract between `A` and `B`  was for $500.  Thus, `B` pays `A` $500.

If `A` is afraid of devaluation, then he must write that into the contract.